# Universal newline support in Ruby that includes \r (CR) line endings

Tags: ruby, file, csv, newline, line-endings

In a Rails app, I'm accepting and parsing CSV files that may come formatted with any of three possible line termination characters: `\n` (`LF`), `\r\n` (`CR+LF`), or `\r` (`CR`). Ruby's `File` and `CSV` libraries seem to handle the first two cases just fine, but the last case ("Mac classic" `\r` line endings) isn't handled as a newline. It's important to be able to accept this format as well as the others, since Microsoft Excel for Mac (running on OS X) seems to use it when exporting to "Comma Separated Values" (although exporting to "Windows Comma Separated" produces the easier-to-handle `\r\n`).

Python has "universal newline support" and will handle any of these three formats without a problem. Is there something similar in Ruby that will accept all three without knowing the format in advance?

Comment: No, Ruby doesn't do that. It senses the OS, and, based on that, assumes the proper line-endings. The old Macintosh `\r` isn't seen in current output since the Mac moved to Mac OS X, which uses *nix `\n`. Show us how you're opening your CSV files and we can probably show you some tricks to handle all the mentioned line-endings with a minor tweak.

Comment: @theTinMan: The problem is that you could get an old-school MacOS CSV file with `\r` EOLs when you're working on Linux which is expecting `\n` EOLs. So the file and the OS won't necessarily agree about what the CSV record separator should be.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use [`:row_sep => :auto`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new):

> **:row_sep**
>   The String appended to the end of each row. This can be set to the special `:auto` setting, which requests that CSV automatically discover this from the data. Auto-discovery reads ahead in the data looking for the next `"\r\n"`, `"\n"`, or `"\r"` sequence.

There are some caveats of course, see the manual linked to above for details.

You could also manually clean up the EOLs with a bit of `gsub`ing before handing the data to CSV for parsing. I'd probably take this route and manually convert all `\r\n`s and `\r`s to single `\n`s before attempting to parse the CSV. OTOH, this won't work that well if there is embedded binary data in your CSV where `\r`s mean something. On the gripping hand, this is CSV we're dealing with so who knows what sort of crazy broken nonsense you'll end up dealing with.

Comment: +1 very nice catch! I hope it reads ahead for every line, because I've encountered CSV files in the past that contained a mixture of line-endings due to someone appending Windows CSV to Mac CSV. It was a PITA.

Comment: @theTinMan: I think `:auto` looks for the first of the three EOLs and applies that to the whole thing. In real life I'd probably preprocess the data to standardize the EOLs to `\n` before doing anything, CSV is such a horribly abused format that you never know what sort of screwed up nonsense you're going to be dealing with.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! And the gsub would be something like `input.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n")`?