# With Ruby, how to import a CSV file that has a row that is missing a value in the last column, and thus ends with a comma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm using Ruby to import a CSV file, and things seem to be working okay, except for the fact that one of the rows ends in a comma, due to the last column having a missing value.

I'm using ruby's native CSV library, with a call:

```
   CSV.open(file, :col_sep => ",")
```

and getting a CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 10),

and if I add a :row_sep call,

```
CSV.open(file, :col_sep => "," , :row_sep => "\r\n")
```

, and getting a CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line endings are probably not `\r\n` then.

You can try using `:row_sep => :auto` (it'll look for different EOLs).

If your CSV file is not supposed to contain fields with multiple lines I'll advice you to clean the whole thing by e.g. `file.gsub(/\r\r?\n?/, "\n")`, and use a simple `"\n"` for row_sep.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969935/4640187