# CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, csv

I have CSV's which I am trying to import into my oracle database but unfortunately I keep on getting the same error:

```
> CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 1).
```

I know there are tons of similar questions which have been asked but none relate specifically to my issue other than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382721/with-ruby-how-to-import-a-csv-file-that-has-a-row-that-is-missing-a-value-in-th) one, but unfortunately it didn't help.

To explain my scenario:

> I have CSV's in which the rows don't always end with a value, but
> rather, just a comma because it's a null value hence it stays blank.
> I would like to import the CSV's regardless of whether the ending is with a comma or without a comma.

Here are the first 5 lines of my CSV with changed values due to privacy reasons,

```
id,customer_id,provider_id,name,username,password,salt,email,description,blocked,created_at,updated_at,deleted_at
1,,1,Default Administrator,admin,1,1," ",Initial default user.,f,2019-10-04 14:28:38.492000,2019-10-04 14:29:34.224000,
2,,2,Default Administrator,admin,2,1,,Initial default user.,,2019-10-04 14:28:38.633000,2019-10-04 14:28:38.633000,
3,1,,Default Administrator,admin,3,1," ",Initial default user.,f,2019-10-04 14:41:38.030000,2019-11-27 10:23:03.329000,
4,1,,admin,admin,4,1," ",,,2019-10-28 12:21:23.338000,2019-10-28 12:21:23.338000,
5,2,,Default Administrator,admin,5,1," ",Initial default user.,f,2019-11-12 09:00:49.430000,2020-02-04 08:20:06.601000,2020-02-04 08:20:06.601000
```

As you can see the ending is sometimes with or without a comma and this structure repeats quite often.

This is my code with which I have been playing around with:

```
def csv_replace_empty_string
  Dir.foreach(Rails.root.join('db', 'csv_export')) do |filename|
    next if filename == '.' or filename == '..' or filename == 'extract_db_into_csv.sh' or filename =='import_csv.rb'
    read_file = File.read(Rails.root.join('db', 'csv_export', filename))
    replace_empty_string = read_file.gsub(/(?<![^,])""(?![^,])/, '" "')
    format_csv = replace_empty_string.gsub(/\r\r?\n?/, "\n")
    # format_csv = remove_empty_lines.sub!(/(?:\r?\n)+\z/, "")
    File.open(Rails.root.join('db', 'csv_export', filename), "w") {|file| file.puts format_csv }
  end
end
```

I have tried using many different kinds of `gsubs` found online in similar forums, but it didn't help.

Here is my function for importing the CSV in the db:

```
def import_csv_into_db
  Dir.foreach(Rails.root.join('db', 'csv_export')) do |filename|
    next if filename == '.' or filename == '..' or filename == 'extract_db_into_csv.sh' or filename =='import_csv.rb'
      filename_renamed = File.basename(filename, File.extname(filename)).classify
        CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('db', 'csv_export',filename), :headers => true, :skip_blanks => true) do |row|
          class_name = filename_renamed.constantize
          class_name.create!(row.to_hash)
          puts "Insert on table #{filename_renamed} complete"
        end
      end
  end
```

I have also tried the options provided by CSV such as `:row_sep => :"\n"` or `:row_sep => "\r"` but keep on getting the same error.

I am pretty sure I have some sort of thinking error, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using the following:

> `format_csv = replace_empty_string.gsub(/\r\r?\n?/, "\n")`

This was originally [@mgrims answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382721/with-ruby-how-to-import-a-csv-file-that-has-a-row-that-is-missing-a-value-in-th), but I had to adjust my code by further removing the `:skip_blanks :row_sep` options.

It is importing successfully now!